# How to change certain characters of files within a folder

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory

I have a folder named "animals"

Inside the folder I have the following files:

```
"cat.PNG", "dog.PNG", "horse.PNG", "sheep.PNG"
```

I know the following code will change the files to lowercase

```
files = os.listdir('.')
for f in files:
    new = f.lower()
    os.rename(f, new)
```

But how would I change this if I wanted the file type to be lower and the name of the animal to be upper of every file?

Comment: You'd ask yourself two questions: "Can I split a file name into path and extension?", and "Can I change one string to upper case and another string to lowercase?" Programming, like most other problems in life, can be solved by breaking your problem into smaller, manageable pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way (which works for any directory and any extension too):

```
for f in os.listdir(source_dir):
    name,ext = os.path.splitext()    
    os.rename(os.path.join(source_dir,f), os.path.join(source_dir,name+ext.lower())
```

- split name into radix+extension
- convert extension to lowercase
- perform rename with full path

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution would be the following:

```
for f in files:
    new = f.upper()
    new.replace(".PNG", ".png")
    os.rename(f, new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file name, do each operation individually, then rejoin them.

```py
files = os.listdir('.')
for f in files:
    # Split the filename by '.'
    split_filename = f.split('.')

    filename = ".".join(split_filename[:-1])
    extension = split_filename[:-1]

    # Do each operation
    filename = filename.upper()
    extension = extension.lower()

    # Rejoin the filename
    new_filename = filename + '.' + extension

    # Rename the file
    os.rename(new_filename, new)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(base, ext) = f.split('.')
new_name = f'{c.upper()}.{d.lower()}'
os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Comment: careful as there may be more than 1 dot in the filename

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and join, see this example:

```
file_names = ["cat.PNG", "dog.PNG", "horse.PNG", "sheep.PNG"]

for file_name in file_names:
    name, extension = file_name.split('.')

    print('.'.join([name.upper(), extension.lower()]))
```

Comment: fails if there is more than 1 dot in the filename